Pandas read_json Future Warning: The behavior of 'to_datetime' with 'unit' when parsing strings is deprecated
I am updating pandas version from 1.3.5 to 2.2.2 on an old project. I am not very familiar with pandas, and I am stuck with a Future Warning:
FutureWarning:
The behavior of 'to_datetime' with 'unit' when parsing strings is deprecated. In a future version, strings will be parsed as datetime strings, matching the behavior without a 'unit'. To retain the old behavior, explicitly cast ints or floats to numeric type before calling to_datetime.
Here is the causes the error:
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import json
>>> import pandas
>>> 
>>> str = '{"Keyword":{"0":"TELECOM","1":"OPERATOR","Total":"Total"},"Type":{"0":"job_field","1":"title_class","Total":null},"Seniority Score":{"0":0.0,"1":-1.0,"Total":-1.0}}'
>>> df = pandas.read_json(StringIO(str), typ='frame', orient='records')

From what I get, it has to do something with integers and floats, probably being represented as strings in the json, but I tried various combinations and can not get arround the warning. I am confused becase I am not calling the to_datetime function at all.

That is probably a pandas bug!

Could be a pandas bug like this one: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47576

The warning indicates that in the future versions to_datetime will only accept strings as input as opposed to current version where you can specify the unit (string or int). But it's strange it's giving you this warning since I neither see a clear link to calling to_datetime in your provided snippet nor any timestamp data within your json.

The json parser may be calling to datetime as part of its internal logic to identify datatypes - one can imagine that separating "2001-01-01" as date vs string might go this way ... but I'm only guessing.

This error is due to having a mix of number-like and strings in the index.
A minimal reproducible example that triggers the error would be:
s = '{"A":{"0":"X","Y":"Y"}}'
pandas.read_json(StringIO(s), typ='frame', orient='records')

Pandas uses to_datetime to infer the dtype of the index, which triggers the warning.
This should most likely be considered a minor bug since this only triggers a warning. Maybe still worth reporting but it might be that no action will be taken.

Thanks, for the info I downgraded to the 1.5.x branch for now
